# Firefox sending multiple XHR requests when binding a controller function to the DOM

Tags: firefox, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have the following function in my controller:

```
$scope.model.listApplicantStatuses = function(){
    var statusChoices = jobsService.getApplicantStatuses();

    if(statusChoices !== null)
            return statusChoices;

    //if($scope.model.listApplicantStatuses.inProgress)
    //  return;
    //$scope.model.listApplicantStatuses.inProgress = true;
    jobsService.fetchApplicantStatuses().then(function(data){
        jobsService.setApplicantStatuses(data.data);
        return data.data;
    },
    function(data){
        $scope.layout.showNotification('error', 10 * 1000, 'we are is experiencing technical difficulties <a href="mailto:support@" class="btn btn-danger">Contact Support</a>');
    });
}
```

corresponding service code:

```
jobsServ.fetchApplicantStatuses = function(){
    return $http.get(utils.getBaseUrl() + '/applications/status_choices', utils.getConfig());
}
jobsServ.getApplicantStatuses = function(){
    return that.applicantStatusChoices;
},
jobsServ.setApplicantStatuses = function(choices){
    that.applicantStatusChoices = choices;
},
```

Example DOM usage:

```
<select class="statusSelect" data-ng-model="model.editedApplicant[applicant.id].status" data-ng-show="layout.statusVisible(applicant.id) && !layout.statusLoader[applicant.id]" data-ng-options="key as val for (key, val) in model.listApplicantStatuses()" data-ng-change="model.updateStatus(applicant.id)"></select>
```

Now, the problem that I am having is that while chrome waits until the first function call completes, and then gives me the data that I get from the AJAX call, and returns undefined in the meanwhile, Firefox calls the function over and over again, creating a whole lot of uneeded XHR requests.

I commented out the code that was setting the inProgress $scope variable, a because it seems to much of a jQurish solution to me, and because that would force me to change my code in many places, and create another Boolean flag such as this per every request to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect the Firefox behaviour. Perhaps you should change the logic as:

```
// a variable to keep statuses, or a promise
$scope.applicantStatusList = $scope.model.listApplicantStatuses();
```

Change `listApplicantStatuses()` to return the promise:

```
$scope.model.listApplicantStatuses = function() {
    var statusChoices = jobsService.getApplicantStatuses();

    if(statusChoices !== null)
        return statusChoices;

    return jobsService.fetchApplicantStatuses().then(function(data){
        jobsService.setApplicantStatuses(data.data);
        return data.data;
    },
    function(data){
        $scope.layout.showNotification(...);
    });
};
```

And use the `applicantStatusList` in the `<select>`:

```
<select ... data-ng-options="key as val for (key, val) in applicantStatusList" ...></select>
```

Comment: But you are returning plain data, not a promise as in $q.promise

Comment: No, it returns the promise that is returned by `then()`, if the data do not exist. If they do exist, then they are returned as is. This is to follow your design; otherwise I would return a promise anyway and, if the data is already there, I would resolve it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by allocating a local variable named _root at the function that sends the xhr, setting _root.ingProgress to true once the request is send, and switching it to false once an answer is received.

Works like a charm.

code:

```
$scope.model.listApplicantStatuses = function(){
    var statusChoices = jobsService.getApplicantStatuses();

    if(statusChoices !== null)
            return statusChoices;
    var _root = this;
    if(_root.inProgress)
        return;

    _root.inProgress = true;
    jobsService.fetchApplicantStatuses().then(function(data){
        jobsService.setApplicantStatuses(data.data);
        _root.inProgress = false;
        return data.data;
    },
    function(data){
        _root.inProgress = false;
        $scope.layout.showNotification('error', 10 * 1000, 'We are currently experiencing technical difficulties <a href="mailto:support@" class="btn btn-danger">Contact Support</a>');
    });
}
```